# Meu notebook jupyter so da erro pelo vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ciência-de-dados, jupyter-notebook

É a primeira vez que tenho problemas no jupyter pelo vscode. Já testei o mesmo código no colab e no proprio jupyter e rodou sem problemas, mas no vscode da erro. Gostaria de conseguir solucionar esse problema do vscode. Saber se isso acontece so no meu vscode e se alguém consegue me ajudar?
'**arquivo.ipynb**'

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andre-marcos-perez/ebac-course-utils/develop/dataset/credito.csv', na_values='na')


sns.set_style("whitegrid")

df_adimplente = df[df['default'] == 0]
df_inadimplente = df[df['default'] == 1]

coluna = 'escolaridade'
titulos = ['Escolaridade dos Clientes', 'Escolaridade dos Clientes Adimplentes', 'Escolaridade dos Clientes Inadimplentes']

eixo = 0
max_y = 0
max = df.select_dtypes('object').describe()[coluna]['freq'] * 1.1
figura, eixos = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(20, 5), sharex=True)

for dataframe in [df, df_adimplente, df_inadimplente]:

  df_to_plot = dataframe[coluna].value_counts().to_frame()
  df_to_plot.rename(columns={coluna: 'frequencia_absoluta'}, inplace=True)
  df_to_plot[coluna] = df_to_plot.index
  df_to_plot.sort_values(by=[coluna], inplace=True)
  df_to_plot.sort_values(by=[coluna])

  f = sns.barplot(x=df_to_plot[coluna], y=df_to_plot['frequencia_absoluta'], ax=eixos[eixo])
  f.set(title=titulos[eixo], xlabel=coluna.capitalize(), ylabel='Frequência Absoluta')
  f.set_xticklabels(labels=f.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)

  _, max_y_f = f.get_ylim()
  max_y = max_y_f if max_y_f > max_y else max_y
  f.set(ylim=(0, max_y))

  eixo += 1

figura.show()
```

[Imagem de ValueError dada pelo vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zDTU.png)
[Imagem o que o código deveria mostrar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17QQI.png)

Comment: vscode não ta causando o erro, Mesmo inicializando o `jupyter`  por  um terminal ou pelo promt de comando apresentara essa notificações o `IDE`não é a causa, no **colab**  a identação é automática (caso estiver ativa) e ambos tratam espaço de forma diferente. É coisa minima mas pode ocorrer.

Comment: No caso não acho que é a identeção, eu abrio o mesmo arquivo no colab, jupyter e vscode. E apenas no vscode ele da erro.